# Decomposition of the second moment of a circular distribution

Tags: variance, expected-value, moments, circular-statistics, bias-variance-tradeoff

When we have a "usual" random variable $X$ on the real line, we can break down the second moment.

$$ 
\mathbb{E}[X^2] = (\mathbb{E}[X])^2 + var(X)
$$

Is there an equivalent for a circular distribution?

Comment: What do you understand by a circular distribution and how do you define its variance?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I’m not sure what I mean by a circular distribution or it’s variance. I now think that “circular” isn’t even correct, because we don’t wrap around completely, just around a semicircle.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics#Moments.  For semicircular data, the simple expedient of doubling the angle turns them into circular data.